# Rails 3 - Set a conversation_id for private messaging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement a simple private messaging feature between users for my Rails app.  I think that I have my models (User & Message) set up correctly to send/receive simple private messages.  However, now I would like to add a reply feature which would seem to require some kind of thread - therefore, I am trying to use a conversation_id column in the messages table to track this.  Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can initially set a conversation_id?  AND then set it again for the subsequent reply messages?

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Additionally, I think this will be helpful to a lot of novice programmers looking to add this same feature.  Thanks.

User Model

```
has_many :sent_messages,     :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
has_many :received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
```

Message Model

```
belongs_to :sender,       :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :receiver,     :class_name => "User"  
belongs_to :conversation, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "conversation_id"
has_many   :replies,      :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "conversation_id"

after_save :set_conversation_id  #only if nil (see private method below)

private

def set_conversation_id
  if self.conversation_id.nil?
    primary_key = self.id
    self.update_attributes(:conversation_id => primary_key)
  end
end
```

The New Message Form (messages/new.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :receiver_id, { :value => params[:user_id] } %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :sender_id, { :value => params[:sender_id] } %>

  <%= f.label :subject %>
  <%= f.text_field :subject %>

  <%= f.label :body %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>

  <%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Messages Controller

```
def new
  @message = Message.new
end

def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
 if @message.save
   flash[:success] = "Message sent!"
   redirect_to root_path
 else
   render 'new'
 end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Method 1

Going off what you started ...

You can start by having a `Conversation` model that `has_many` messages. When a new thread is created, create a new `Conversation` and use its ID for the first message. When a message is created as a reply to an existing message, copy over the message's `conversation_id`.

```
# new conversation
conv = Conversation.create # parameters ...
message = conv.messages.build # parameters ...

# reply
message = origin.conv.messages.build # parameters
```

This, however, does not keep track of the order of the messages.

## Method 2

What I would have done ...

I would let each message have a `parent_id` that is the primary key of a message it's a reply to. If a message is "root", then this field will be empty. At runtime, this can be used to derive the conversation threads.

```
class Message
  has_one :child, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Message'
  # ...
```

## Method 3

Use or adapt from [acts_as_messageable](https://github.com/LTe/acts-as-messageable).

Comment: Jim, I'm gonna try your Method 2 (to avoid an additional model).  What do you think about running an after_save callback on the Message model to set the conversation_id equal to the primary_key (if conversation_id does not already exist - ie, for the first message)?  I have updated my code above to show you what I mean.

Comment: I wouldn't do that, unless it's CLEARLY documented. Future-me will probably write some kind of infinite loop while tracing messages.